# Is it possible to make Modbook-style tablets from MacBook Pros ...?

Tags: macbook-pro, customization, touchscreen

I ask this question because the Axiotron website and their [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/modbook) presence seems to suggest stasis and/or the end of the company. Hence the DIY approach.

A few years back I lusted after a [Modbook](http://www.axiotron.com/index.php?id=modbook) from Axiotron - they would take your Macbook and put a touchscreen panel on the top. This would give you a tablet with some serious grunt and connectivity.

I was wondering if it would be possible to do something similar with my current 13" MacBook Pro and, if so, how difficult/expensive/tricky would it be? I'm not bothered about multi-touch (tho it would obviously be very nice), just basic point, click/double click, drag functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this [*neowin.net* forum post](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/896998-project-macbook-tablet/). A poster provides a detailed guide to converting an older plastic macbook into a working tablet.

Unfortunately, applying his approach to a newer unibody MacBook or MacBook Pro would be difficult since much of the structural rigidity of those notebooks lies in the keyboard plate. Cutting away that metal to fit your touch screen or pen tablet would leave only the relatively flimsy outer shell to support the notebook. Axiotron addressed this problem in their proposed (and now probably dead) [Modbook Pro](http://www.axiotron.com/index.php?id=modbookpro) by building their own housing for the MacBook internals.

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing this with a Macbook Air. Just take off the hinges and fold the screen to the back. Make sure all wires are secure using crazy glue and tape

Comment: That's insane! Do you have photos? ;-)